# Installation problem libssh2-php on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: server, apt, php

New here, be gentle...

I am setting up a server using Ubuntu Server 13.10 64 bit. So far all went well, but now running into a problem during installation of libssh2-php.

```
Setting up libssh2-php (0.11.3-0.1build2) ...

Creating config file /etc/php5/conf.d/ssh2.ini with new version
cp: cannot create regular file â/etc/php5/conf.d/ssh2.iniâ: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing libssh2-php (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssh2-php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge libssh2-php` followed by reinstalling, no luck.
When I check `/etc/php5/`, there is a /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d and a /etc/php5/cli/conf.d directory but no /etc/php5/conf.d directory.

Edit php version 5.5.3

Any suggestions welcome... Thanks!

Comment: What was the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` after reinstalling?

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report. You can try , as a work around, `sudo mkdir -p /etc/php5/conf.d/ && sudo install libssh2-php`. If that fails, run `sudo touch /etc/php5/conf.d/ssh2.ini && sudo install libssh2-php`

Comment: @AvinashRaj - /etc/php5/conf.d is the config directory for php5 and usually contains things such as php.ini The "â" is a translation problem see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f results in the same error.

Comment: Manually creating /etc/php5/conf.d does solve the issue, no need to touch the ini file first. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Found out there is already a bug filed for this problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-ssh2/+bug/1237967

This also confirms the workaround suggested by bodhi.zazen

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-ssh2/+bug/1237967).

As a workaround:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/php5/conf.d/ 
sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
```